# Conditional formatting formula not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My conditional formating formula is ignoring one of the conditions. I have 3 conditions but one is being ignored.

My table looks like this and I am trying to highlight the charge sell according to if charge is above or below a pre-determined amount. The amount is conditional on grade and row label

```
Row label .      Grade .         Charge
Core .            Specialist .     115
Unsocial .        Trainee          56
Core .            Trainee .        67
Unsocial .        Consultant .     110
Unsocial          Specialist .     114
```

I have tried

```
=AND(A2="Core",B2="Trainee",C2<=111)
```

The formula is working with the charge and row label condition but not the grade condition as it highlights rows with the wrong grade.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: In the rule what is the `Applies To:` Range?

Comment: It's not clear on what you want to 'highlight' but if you want the row from A:C then select A2:C6 as the *Applies To::* and use `=AND($A2="Core", $B2="Trainee", $C2<=111)`. That should highlight A4:C4.

Comment: Use the code of @user11370591 and your _applies to_ will be `=$C$2:$C$6`. So, it will only highlight your `Charge` cell.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear on what you want to 'highlight' but if you want the row from A:C then select A2:C6 as the *Applies To::* and use

```
=AND($A2="Core", $B2="Trainee", $C2<=111)
```

That should highlight A4:C4. All conditional formatting rules are relative to the cell in the top left corner of the *Applies To::* range. If you are covering multiple columns then you have to make the columns in your formula absolute. If they remain relative, C2 sees the formula as,

```
'example of the WRONG formula
=AND(C2="Core", D2="Trainee", E2<=111)
```